# Writing an HTML string to a file with jenkins/sh

Tags: jenkins, sh

I have a variable containing an HTML file string (basically an E2E test result) in my jenkinspipeline:

```
OUT = sh(script: "kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig-${scenario} logs \$(kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig-${scenario} get pods --selector=job-name=greyboxtest -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')", returnStdout:true)
HTML = OUT.substring(OUT.indexOf('HTMLSTART')+9, OUT.indexOf('HTMLEND')-1)
echo(HTML)
sh "echo ${HTML} >> ./reports/test.html"
```

However, the echo line gives me the following error: `Syntax error: newline unexpected`. I suspect it's because of the special characters like `<`, `>` or something like that. since the JSON version of the testresult works using the same method.

Is there any other way or trick to write the HTML string to the filesystem?

Comment: `OUT2 = OUT.replaceAll(~/[\r\n]/, " ")` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of doing it a little Groovier, so to speak.

```
node() {
    stage ('WriteHTMLOutput') {
        OUT = sh(script: "kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig-${scenario} logs \$(kubectl --kubeconfig ./kubeconfig-${scenario} get pods --selector=job-name=greyboxtest -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')", returnStdout:true)
        HTML = OUT.substring(OUT.indexOf('HTMLSTART')+9, OUT.indexOf('HTMLEND')-1)
        sh "rm -f /tmp/test.html"
        f = new File("/tmp/test.html")
        f.append("${HTML}")
    }
}
```